# How to set a CheckBox value from code?

Tags: forms, checkbox, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a checkBox, enum type `NoYes`.
I want to set a value to **CheckBox** control in my Form equal to a Table field value, using X++ code.

For example, I want have the same value for CheckBox equal to value Enum  field `TableA.FieldEnum`.

How I have to do?

Thanks for your time!

Enjoy!

Comment: Do you want to dynamically link a control (of type `checkBox`) to field in data source or do you want to change the `checked` status of the control to a value?

Comment: The first solution Maxim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `datasource` and `dataField` methods on the control:

```
mycheckBox.datasource("TableA"); //Data source name
mycheckBox.dataField(fieldNum(TableA, FieldEnum));
```

Don't forget to set `AutoDeclaration` of the myCheckBox control to `Yes`.

Comment: Thanks Maxim for help!